# How to implement a certain drop-down menu in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, drop-down-menu

I want to implement the following menu in WPF. Note that the "+" sign changes to a "-" when the Apple button is clicked. And in the opened submenu A.1 to A.5, the mouse over item is highlighted.

How am I going to do this?

There are four options:

[image: Closed]

The Apple menu is open:

[image: Open]

Comment: Use the Expander control. Write a new template. Not that hard.

Comment: @EdPlunkett It is not an expander. The menu items Banana to Durian are hidden behind the Apple menu; they are not pushed down.

Comment: Huh, OK. Sounds like it's just a regular menu, retemplated. The popup doesn't have to go to the right.

Comment: But a regular menu is horizontal. How do I make a new template so that the menu is vertical?

Comment: Create a menu, go into the designer, right click, and select "edit a copy of template" or something -- it'll give you a copy of the menu template. It's a lot of XAML. But going through it, you can figure out what the visual states and such are, and how to do the popups and such.

Comment: I am new to WPF. Where can I find a good tutorial on templates?

Answer (score 1):

I think control you are looking for is Accordian Control. You can find a good example of accordian [here](http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2010/02/20/How-to-play-the-Accordion-WPF-Toolkit.aspx)